# First nautilus instance not showing / mounting (removable) devices in places pane

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, devices

Since a number of weeks I am having a strange issue with nautilus. Before when I inserted a CD, I would be prompted for an action, if I inserted a USB stick it would be automatically mounted and shown and disk partitions that were not automatically mounted at boot time were shown under Devices in the Places pane.
Then a number of weeks ago this just stopped working, I have a hunch that this happened when I created an additional account that was activated for automatic login for a while.
I have found out that when I just kill the initial nautilus -n instance started by gnome-session and then restart it from the desktop it will show the available devices (like an inserted CD) and I can then mount them by clicking. (Alternatively I can logout from the desktop and back on again). Still, this is pretty annoying to have to do time and again.
Yes I know about the configuration settings that have to do with this and yes the automount settings are activated.

I thought that there was maybe a relationship with the automatic logon but that appears not to be the case, if I disable that nautilus is still failing to show the devices the first time I login but showing them after logging out and back in again.
This is Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit, fully updated.

Answer (score 1):

I now believe this issue is caused by gdu-notification-daemon crashing, which is a known bug (#932662).